# How do I increase the speed of this loop or pixel color finding process?

Tags: java, performance, beginner

I've been working on a program that should find the color red on the screen and then send out an alert. The issue is that the red color moves around a lot and the color finder moves too slow on the screen to find the color accuritely and in time before the color dissapears to another location on the screen.

Is there a way to speed up this color finding process so that it is practically instant?

Here is the code:

ColorFinder.java

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class ColorFinder
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
    {
        //Create memories
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        String ans;
        int red;
        int green;
        int blue;

        int x=535;
        int y=168;

        //Prints instructions
        System.out.println("Type 'p' to start.");

        System.out.println("");

        //Waits for start input
        ans = scanner.nextLine();

        if(ans.equals("p"))
        {
            //Starts loop
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            {

                i=0;
                System.out.println("");
                


                //Color searcher
                x=x+1;

                if(x>1378 && y>468) //reset on highest values x & y
                {
                    x=535; y=168;
                }
                if(x>1378) //step down by one pixel with y
                {
                    y=y+1;
                    x=535;
                }

                //Get RGB value on screen coords
                
                System.out.println("x:"+x+" y:"+y);//this part is not needed, it's only for visualising if it's working or at what speed it moves
                
                Color color = robot.getPixelColor(x, y);
                red=color.getRed();
                green=color.getGreen();
                blue=color.getBlue();

                /*
                System.out.println("Red   = " + red);
                System.out.println("Green = " + green);
                System.out.println("Blue  = " + blue);
                */


//Remove the note marks below to see how fast it moves
/*
robot.mouseMove(x, y);
if(x==1000)
{break;}
*/

                //if it finds the specific red color it stops the loop and prints out "Found red color!"
                if(red==255 && green==20 && blue==25)
                {
                    System.out.println("Found red color!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will gladly answer any questions.
Any kind of solution that does the same thing but way faster is good, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the red region you trying to find exactly 1 pixel? If not, you don't need to scan every pixel. For example, if you have a 10px red square somewhere on the screen, you only need to  scan every 10th pixel at x and y. And I don't know how java handles console output but on other languages I saw a pretty big slowdown if I tryed to write at a very high speed to the console.

Comment: It has to read basically every single pixel in an area, I will add more shades of red and also white shades once the color searching stuff is complete. I actually had the same idea, I tried it and it didnt find the right color or shade of red, it basically skipped over it on a still image.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question brings back memories from 2010 when I asked how to draw constantly changing grapics
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742731/java-how-to-draw-constantly-changing-graphics

The idea is that you prepare a location rectangle of the area you want to capture and ask the robot to fill it:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(p.x - 4, p.y - 4, 8, 8);
final BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
```

then you loop over the area checking for the match

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        final Color pixelColor = new Color(capture.getRGB(x, y));

        if (!pixelColor.equals(view.getColorAt(x, y))) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Typically my computer vision AI's does not use 64-pixel area, but 64*64=4096, but you can use 4k screenshot has 3840x2160=8294400 pixels and a minimum of 8 million comparisons will actually take some time unless you parallelize the work.

---

I write c#, so this is written from the head as I remember Java +10 years ago.

```
Color red = new Color(255, 20, 25); 
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(535, 168, 843, 300);
final BufferedImage capture = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
Pair<String, Integer> location = FindColor(capture, red);
if(location != null){
    System.out.printf("Found red color at (x:{%s}, y: {%s})%n", 
        location.getValue(0), 
        location.getValue(1));
```

where FindColor is something in the lines of:

```
public Pair<String, Integer> FindColor(BufferedImage capture, Color color){
  if (capture == null || color == null) 
      return null;  
  for (int x = 0; x < capture.getWidth(); x++)
      for (int y = 0; y < capture.getHeight(); y++)
          if (new Color(capture.getRGB(x, y)).equals(color)) 
              return Pair.with(x, y);     
  return null;
}
```

instead of tuple-like Pair<>, you can use point2d or a similar struct just likely you do not need the null checks.

Comment: You can use a punch of tricks if you just have to quickly find 64x64 rows and columns from a solid background where it is. For example, if you "binary and" all row pixels together they will be your background unless the object is in one of them. Loop itself should be simple and index cached. So complexity O(n^2) is reduced to O(2n).

Comment: Could you please change the code I posted to make it work? I'm just so frusturated because I don't understand how to implement this screenCapture thing. I just want it to be in that same rectangle where it is in my code and not the entire screen.

Comment: @Golden The Rectangle class gives you the possibility of specifying the [`x`, `y`, `width` & `height`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Rectangle.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,int,int,int)) as shown in Margus's example. To replicate the same example with your code, you need to changes / adapt the indexes `x` & `y` to iterate within the `width` & `height` of the `Rectangle` /  `ScreenCapture`.

Comment: @Doi9t I managed to make it work now but it seems like it only takes one screenshot, I need it to take every frame. Even if the color dissapears from the rectangle now it still says "Found red color!". How do I make it take another capture and forget the old one?
I basically want it to update with a new capture every frame.

Comment: @Golden You can recreate a new capture by recalling the `variable = robot.createScreenCapture(rect);` method at the end of the scan, and restart the loop.

Answer (score 3):

The bottleneck in your code is mostly because you use a method (`java.awt.Robot#getPixelColor`) in a loop to fetch the color pixel by pixel; this method uses lower system API to fetch the color and that takes more time.

You could make the code faster by using the `java.awt.Robot#createScreenCapture` to create a screenshot of a certain region and then, iterate on the colors by using the `java.awt.image.BufferedImage#getRGB`. The only downside is that the method returns an integer containing the [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) instead of a color object, you will need to convert it to a color.

To convert the RGB to single color, you can use the `java.awt.image.ColorModel` to read the RGB value and choose the different color individually.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! I have three questions though, does this screenshot get saved somewhere or is it literally just faster? Second question would be: How would this be done with the code I posted here? Third question would be: How fast is it really? Since I need it to be basically detecting every movement of the color it has to be really fast (under a second).

Comment: The screenshot is kept in memory; the code will be faster, since you won’t be using the IO to fetch the values (only one time, for the screenshot).

Comment: I'm not sure how I could implement that into the code I have, could you give an example. Having a hard time finding out how to actually implement it into my code.